# JAVA Hashtable find maximum value

Tags: java, hashtable, enumeration, max

I want to find the largest value in a `Hashtable` of `Integer` values. Is there any quick and efficient way to achieve this?

This is my code...

```
Hashtable<String,Integer> h = new Hashtable<String,Integer>();

h.add( "a",1 );
h.add( "b",5 );
h.add( "c",3 );
h.add( "d",5 );
h.add( "e",2 );
h.add( "f",1 );

int max = ???;
```

I need to find the maximum value, which in the example above is `5`. The `Hashtable` will always be small, less than 100 entries on average.

Comment: iterate through the hashtable?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use [`Collections#max()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max%28java.util.Collection%29) on [`Map#values()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values%28%29).

```
int max = Collections.max(h.values());
```

Note that you should be using [`Map#put()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put%28K,%20V%29) to put the elements, there's no `Map#add()`.

Answer (score 1):

a) don't you write

```
h.put ("a", 1);
```

b) Can't you get the values like this:

```
java.util.Collection <Integer> ci = h.values (); 
// [1, 5, 3, 5, 2, 1]
```

Now search the values.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
new TreeSet(h.values()).last()
```

Comment: But it will always be slower than iterating through the values.